Multiple API testing e2e with different bodies and responses
We have what we call an aggregator in our company, basically we have more than 15 APIs, all which have different headers, bodies and also expect different responses.
We aggregate and consume those APIs and then resell one API which basically has the possibility of using the 15 APIs.
There are very strict workflows and all 15 APIs have a few fields which are mandatory in each of their requests.
The workflow is for example to check for idempotency, or that call X cannot be executed after B has been executed etc.
I have been trying to do this with Postman but setting up these conditions, copying the request over and over again, just so I can test the workflow which has about 50 steps (mix and match) per API is time consuming and problematic if one step is missed.
I want to be able to set 1 workflow for all APIs and then be able to run any of them (considering they have a set body/template with variables)
how can we achieve this without having to define each request more than once
example: we want to avoid this duplication seen here
stack: lamp+php+mariadb

This seems more like a QA question than PHP, or I'm misreading it. I would like at playwright or selenium.

yes and no, problem is, most of the team only knows PHP, and asking to write Js for example, can be problematic, but thank you, selenium definitely no, but I'll have a look at playwright
